# Shopify checkout Python script shipping error

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm trying to make a Python Shopify buy bot script with the following

JSON payload

```
{
    'utf8': '✓',
    '_method': 'patch',
    'authenticity_token': '',
    'previous_step': 'payment_method',
    'step': '',
    's': 'east-66ff824e354621d8fcedf11a05967ac6',
    'checkout[payment_gateway]': '83961729',
    'checkout[credit_card][vault]': 'false',
    'checkout[different_billing_address]': 'true',
    'checkout[billing_address][first_name]': 'xxx',
    'checkout[billing_address][last_name]': 'xxx',
    'checkout[billing_address][address1]': 'xxx',
    'checkout[billing_address][address2]': '',
    'checkout[billing_address][city]': 'xxx',
    'checkout[billing_address][country]': 'xxx',
    'checkout[billing_address][province]': 'xxx',
    'checkout[billing_address][zip]': 'xxx',
    'checkout[billing_address][phone]': 'xxx',
    'checkout[shipping_rate][id]': 'shopify-UPS®%20Ground-12.03',
    'checkout[shipping_rate][price]': '12.03',
    'checkout[shipping_rate][title]': 'UPS®%20Ground',
    'complete': '1',
    'checkout[client_details][browser_width]': '1307',
    'checkout[client_details][browser_height]': '1690',
    'checkout[client_details][javascript_enabled]': '1',
    'g-recaptcha-repsonse': '',
    'button': ''
}
```

Python code

```
import requests
import urllib3

session = requests.session()
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

r = add_to_cart(session, variant)
cj = r.cookies
link = "https://store.merchant.com/14391668/checkouts/"

r = session.post(link, cookies=cj, data=payload, verify=True)
```

But I keep getting this error from the `r.text`

`Your cart has been updated and the previous shipping rate isn’t valid. Select a new rate.`

What do I miss to successfully checkout?

Comment: I'll be diffiicult to get help here if it's a non technical question.
Your code looks ok. The server answered.
What's the value of `r.code` ? 200 ?
It looks like it's a functional error related to Shopify business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You made an assumption the price is hard coded here. It is fetched from the merchant. I figured out the the issue wss because the shipping_rate:id was incorrect.